# How to implement banner rotating in Mono/ASP.NET MVC2 application

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, banner

Shopping cart admin can upload banner images and ASP.NET /Mono MVC2 C# application stores them in database.
They can retrieved by url like /GetImage?Id=1 , /GetImage?Id=2  etc.
Banners are stored in database in same site, application has full control over loading and storing them. Banners from external sites are not used.

How to create control shows rotating banners in top of cart page ?

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_adrotator.asp  contians ASP.NET banner rotate control. Is it best way to use it in MVC2 application ? I havent seen that this is implemented in Mono . So I cannot probably use it since application must run in Mono 2.10 also.

Uploaded banners can be different sizes. So server or rotator should probably resize them to make them to same size.
How to implement it ? Is there some simple MVC code or control or plugin for this ?

jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET/Mono MVC2 , C# are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, you do not have server controls like what you have in webforms to do this. You can achieve this by using some client side plugin.

jQuery Cycle plugin is a nice plugin which does this.http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/. you need to load the images to your markup.

Comment: Thank you. In my case number of possible images are thousands. Image url cannot added to markup, they should loaded dynamically. I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807250/how-to-enhance-image-tumbnails-auto-refresh